# Как реализовать фрагмент макета psd

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу понять, как правильно реализовать вставку иконок через фоновое изображение так, чтобы текст располагался справа, а не под картинкой при переносе строк. Желательно без использования обтекания.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У контейнера ставите фоном иконку, `padding-left` и все. Тут не нужны псевдоэлементы, отдельные элементы и тп

Answer (score 1):

Решение через фоновую картиyку

```
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img"></div>
        <div class="item-text">
          Натуральные ингредиенты
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img"></div>
        <div class="item-text">
          Доставка бесплатно при заказе от 2000 рублей
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/no-translate-detected_318-60914.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.item-text {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

Решение через Img

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/no-translate-detected_318-60914.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="item-text">
      Натуральные ингридиенты
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/no-translate-detected_318-60914.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="item-text">
      Доставка бесплатно при заказе от 2000 рублей
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.item-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item-text {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажи для img и текста display: inline-block.
А если текст достаточно большой что не помещается рядом с картинкой и уходит вниз то укажи какой нибудь max-width.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, картинки не несут никакой смысловой нагрузки, поэтому тег img здесь не нужен. В описании я написал, что вставка через фоновое изображение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через :before

```
div class="wrap">
    <div class="item-text">
      Натуральные ингредиенты
    </div>
</div>

.item-text{
  position:relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
 }
.item-text:before{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: url(какойто);
  left: -30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я реализую таким способом если не использовать библиотеки.
Такой подход мне нравится тем что очень просто адаптировать под различные устройства добавив пару строк кода родительскому элементу и поиграть со свойством order дочерних элементов.

Добавлю: Иконки можно вставить в сам HTML и лучше в формате base64.

```css
.paren-parent{
  display: flex;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.icon{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/ios/64/000000/fortnite-filled.png);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="paren-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```